# API Limits Exception

Tags: apex, governorlimits, scheduled-apex

We have a customer whom is hitting API limits in their org: More than 50,000 API call per-day.

They're trying to isolate an installed package that might be to blame, and the only thing they've given us to go on is that the user name that is hitting the limit is:

`autoproc@00dd0000000nuy9mae`

Given the name of the user, I assume this means that some sort of scheduled process from an installed package is running and hitting the API limit when it runs.

I can ask them to cancel all scheduled jobs (Of which we're not one) but is there any other way to profile the source of all these API hits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other then having the customer send you debug logs, monitoring scheduled jobs, etc there's not a whole lot you can do.  One thing they could try is uninstalling your app / reinstalling after a period of time to see if the api limits jump up.  It may not be an installed app either.  If multiple developers access the org, that can jump the limits up fairly rapidly as well.

Answer (score 5):

The API Usage report might also give you some hints (reports -> administrative reports-> api usage last 7 days).

Comment: Good idea ... we run the same App in our production org, and we could tell if we're running high on API calls ourselves to see if we're a major contributer

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's a direct way to profile this, per se. But you can continually create new debug logs and also set their API Usage Notifications to alert you when they are getting X% away from running out of available API calls.

Then just look at the debug logs created and see who the API hog is ;)